# How can one webpage be opened in multiple chrome windows for screen size testing

Tags: google-chrome

I have a responsive webpage that I need to test at different resolutions to inspect the layout at these different resolutions.  Is there a command line option that I can use to open one webpage in a bunch of different windows, each with a different resolution like the following?

[image]

I'd love to somehow figure out how to do this without opening a bunch of new windows and then adjusting each of them every time with the [Window Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh) extension.

Comment: Hi Ross, questions about installable software are off-topic here on Web Applications.  I am going to migrate this to [SU] for that reason.  I have also edited out the request for an extension aspect, because that's off-topic on both of the sites.

Comment: Did you try chrome bundle, from google, there is some options that can be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a script called `many_resolutions.py` which is used like:

```
python many_resolutions.py http://localhost:3000 800x600,0,0 1280x1024,2000,0
```

Where the screen spec is `<width>x<height>,<x-position>,<y-position>`.

```
import subprocess, sys, os

CHROME='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
webpage = sys.argv[1]
for screen_spec in sys.argv[2:]:
    split = screen_spec.split(',')
    if len(split) not in (1,3) or 1 > split[0].find('x'): 
        raise Exception('Screen arguments are <width>x<height>,<x-position>,<y-position>')
    screen_res = split[0].split('x')
    pos = None
    if len(split) == 3:
        pos = split[1:3]
    cmd = [
        CHROME,
        '--profile-directory=Default',
        '--app=data:text/html,<html><body><script>' +
        ('window.moveTo(' + pos[0] +',' + pos[1] + ');' if pos else '') +
        'window.resizeTo(' + screen_res[0] + ',' + screen_res[1] + ');' +
        'window.location="' + webpage + '";</script></body></html>',
    ]
    print(cmd)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
```